# Can't fetch single record in Angular js/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Hope you are doing good..

I'm trying to fetch single record from datasource by Id in UI via `Angular-js`.
Using Web-API for retrieving values from DB.

To make it simple : `HTML-->Angular-->WebAPI-->DB`

When i'm trying it says Id passed is Null..Don't know how to rectify.
hope i've missed to fill hole in somewhere....below snippets fr ref.

(Also can u verify/correct me the way i've coded in html is right way to display values fetched by Id)

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="SingleController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="_Id" />
        <input type="button" value="search" ng-click="search()" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>MovieId</td>
                <td>{{MovID}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>{{Movtitle}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Genre</td>
                <td>{{Movgnre}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Classification</td>
                <td>{{Movcls}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ReleaseDate</td>
                <td>{{Movdate}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rating</td>
                <td>{{Movrate}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cast</td>
                <td>{{Cast}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Controller.JS

```
app.controller('SingleController', function ($scope, MyService) {
var Id = $scope._Id;
$scope.search = function (Id) {
    var promiseGetSingle = MyService.getbyId(Id);

    promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
        var res = pl.data;
        $scope.MovID = res._movieId;
        $scope.Movtitle = res._title;
        $scope.Movgnre = res._genre;
        $scope.Movcls = res._classification;
        $scope.Movdate = res._releaseDate;
        $scope.Movrate = res._rating;
        $scope.Cast = res._cast;

        //   $scope.IsNewRecord = 0;
    },
              function (errorPl) {
                  console.log('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
              });
    }
});
```

service.js

```
this.getbyId = function (Id) {
    return $http.get("/api/values/" + Id);
};
```

Please ignore this lengthy snippets.
Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure about the relative URL in your $http.get() function?

Comment: @dustmouse yes .....its correct path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your search function is expecting you to pass a value when it is invoked on ng-click:

```
<input type="button" value="search" ng-click="search(_Id)" />
```

Comment: Thats the answer...great n thnks bro